# Usercontrol interacting with form...?

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am working on a project and I wonder if I can get a UserControl to **Interact** with the form it is in (e.g. get values such as Me.Size.Height or run subroutines like Me.Show() ) and I have no clue how to do that. I don't know if it's even possible.

Comment: try `Me.FindForm.Height`. it is not a great idea to have a subordinate control trying to control the parent form, for that you should consider an Extender.  Getting properties etc is no problem though.

Answer (score 3):

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.parentform(v=vs.110).aspx

use the ParentForm property of your user control